# Tomcat6 configured to use SSL does not work

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, ssl, tomcat6

I am trying to setup SSL to my web app and followed tutorial (http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/), then hitting `http://localhost:8443` returns "unable to connect"

Environment:

Tomcat6, windows 7

Tomcat6 is up and running, `http://localhost:8080` displays tomcat page.

Below is the step I took so far:

**1. Generate keystore file**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin>keytool -genkey -alias masatosanssl -keypass masatosanadmin -keystore masatosanssl.bin -storepass
 masatosanadmin
```

then I answered the questionnaire.

masatosanssl.bin is created and I've moved the file to my webapp dir which is at:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\masatosanssl.bin
```

**2. Configuring Tomcat for using the Keystore file**

Modify server.xml

Location: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\conf`

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
        keystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\head_first\masatosanssl.bin"
        keystorePass="masatosanadmin" 
               />
```

Then I restart tomcat and
hit https://localhost:8443 returns "cannot display page",
I've tried changing server.xml keystoreFile path to relative etc but none seems to work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess if I put .bin file under Program File, it might be blocked by UAC ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try doing it the way described in the *Tomcat* documentation, not some [arbitrary Internet junk](http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps).

Comment: I've followed the documentation and generated .keystore file, also somewhat restarting my computer fixed the problem.. I guess somewhat my tomcat restart wasn't working??? Still investigating.

Answer (score 3):

You are not missing anything except checking the logs. I had the same issue and almost checked everywhere over internet. I was trying to run the web service over tomcat 7.0 and generated the keystore the same way you did.
The issue as Apache documentation for running over ssl says is that if any setting or jar file regarding APR implementation of SSL keys is in tomcat directory, it assumes you are using openssl and not JSSE implementation which can work with keystores generated by keytool.
To localize the source of the problem, I looked at server.xml file in [tomcat dir]/conf and I saw this line was there:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

Then I commented out this line and restart the server. It works now like a charm!

I found the source of error by reading apache docs carefully in addition to looking into the logs. It is always a good practice

Comment: @dementiev: this is an old post and Stackoverflow has several updates causing this line to disappear. I fixed it again and you should be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Tomcat's logs? Failures to start a Connector will typically generate log messages describing exactly why it could not be started.

What does "returns 'cannot display page'" mean? Is the server listening on the port or not? What does `curl -I http://localhost:8443/` or `telnet localhost 8443` show?

And are you really sure you want to store your keypass file under a publically-accessible directory like `webapps/head_first`? Typically this file should be stored in a directory where only the user that Tomcat runs under can read it.